# Emulate Markers in Log4j 1.2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

Is there any way to emulate markers in Log4j 1.2?

I'm sending them from Slf4j but they are erased by [`MarkerIgnoringBase`](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/helpers/MarkerIgnoringBase.html).

I know that Log4j doesn't support Markers by design, but nothing is impossible and there could be some way, maybe some custom LoggerFactory and Log level?

Comment: "*I know that Log4j doesn't support Markers by design*" > Is that true?  http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html

Comment: I mentioned 1.2 in my question... and Log4j 2.x was not available at that time... and it still seems to be in beta... but it's a great news that they are doing a facelift! will keep an eye

Comment: Good point, I should read your question more closely! Actually, 2.x is only in beta I note.

Comment: Great question, 2014 and I have still have this issue.  There is no way for me to go to log4j 2.x at my workplace.  :(